Single customer checkout with mix of products from two separate Stripe accounts?
Using Stripe, with a single customer checkout experience (i.e. customer only makes one payment), is it possible to mix products from two separate Stripe accounts?

Stripe account #1 offers a product with one time pricing
Stripe account #2 offers a subscription product with recurring pricing

Both Stripe accounts should have a Standard dashboard and:

Get a view of the customer details
Be able to refund their portion of the purchase
Control their product pricing

This feels like it should be possible with Stripe's Connect product but I couldn't see a way of making this work. Creating separate charges and transfers felt promising but it looks like the connected accounts would only have access to an Express Dashboard so we'd need to build something custom to facilitate viewing customers, refunding, price control, etc.


Creating separate charges and transfers felt promising but it looks like the connected accounts would only have access to an Express Dashboard so we'd need to build something custom to facilitate viewing customers, refunding, price control, etc.

Technically, no. You can integrate SCT with Standard accounts just as well as any other account type.
Though, SCT+Standard accounts isn't objectively a good match. One of the main issues are refunds - Standard account users can action them, but that won't refund the payment to the customer with SCT > it will reverse the transfer to your platform. You could resolve this with a webhook handler that checks for reversals and refunds the parent charge, but that's an example of custom handling you wouldn't have to do with Express/Custom.
Another issue is the fact that you want products to be created on the connected account.
What you want to do is possible, but if you want one charge for the customer, it can only be with the following restrictions:

The payment takes place on your platform
This means the products and customers are on your platform
Correct amounts can then be transferred accordingly to connected accounts

Technically, you could make this goal of products being created on the Standard account possible - you would again have a webhook handler that checks for updates to products/prices on your connected account, then map products on your platform accordingly.
Then, if a customer orders one_time_price from acct_A + recurring_price from acct_B, you can create a Subscription with the correct prices:

You can create a subscription with the recurring price in items and the one time price in add_invoice_items.
Naturally, the one time price will be charged once, and the recurring price will be charged recurringly.
When a payment succeeds, check the parent invoice for items and dispatch transfers to the relevant accounts.

Trying to make this work with Standard accounts to save you integrating a UI isn't going to save you a lot of work in my opinion - there's the refund issue I mentioned, the product mapping I suggested, and more - like how you would handle disputes, how this may affect the funds available to your platform balance for future transfers, etc.
